# Wordpress doesn't send any email confirmation

Tags: php, smtp, wordpress, buddypress

I have installed BuddyPress and bbpress is WordPress and registered a new user. But it neither send any comfirmation mail in new user's account nor in the admin account of new user notification? What's the prblem? Is any problem related to SMTP sever cofiguration or I have to install any mail plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes BuddyPress runs into issues sending emails with Wordpress's email function.
Try installing [WP-Mail-SMTP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) and configuring that with your SMTP mail settings.

If that doesn't work, see if there are any plugins installed that might be deactivating these emails. For example, the "BP Disable Activation" plugin deactivates both emails. If that's the case, you'll probably have to edit the code of either the plugin or BuddyPress.